# Foxit PDF SDK - delete page increases document size

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, foxit

The DeletePage function found in the Foxit SDK allows a page to be deleted from a PDF.  When a page is deleted and the document saved, the file size of the output document (with fewer pages) is larger than the original.

This can be seen with the PDF sample app which ships with the SDK:

```
$ ./simple_sample/bin/rel_gcc/pdfpage_organization 
...
Success: Use <rb> mode to open the file InsertPages.pdf and associate it with a stream.
Success: Create the file object.
Success: Open file successfully .
Success: Load PDF document successfully.
Success: Get page with index 1.
Success: Delete page with index 1.
Using extension implementation to open the file.
Success: Use <wb> mode to open the file SourcePage_delete.pdf and associate it with a stream.
Success: Create the file object.
Success: The PDF document save to SourcePage_delete.pdf.
```

Examining the output:

ll simple_sample/input_files/SourcePage.pdf 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 richard  staff    **92K** Dec 17  2013 simple_sample/input_files/SourcePage.pdf

ll simple_sample/output_files/pdfpage_organization/SourcePage_delete.pdf 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 richard  staff    **96K** Jun 23 10:22 simple_sample/output_files/pdfpage_organization/SourcePage_delete.pdf

SourcePage_delete.pdf does have one less page as expected, but is 4k bigger.  I can get the same result deleting 99 pages from a 100 page document, i.e. the file size does not reflect the page count.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what the document's internals look like. Can you post before and after files somewhere?

Comment: Yes, here they are: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9nx8j6v7421cg4f/AABpI1cbZoNmE4atTH8Hdb7sa

Comment: It is possible (I do not know the Foxit SDK) that the delete and save operation are performed in incremental update mode. In this situation the page is only marked as deleted and additional structures are added so the final size is larger than the original.

Comment: I can imagine that being the case.  Is there another mode which would force the removal of the structures contained in the page?

Comment: There could be a few reasons for this. Perhaps the original PDF was missing some required element and in the process of saving the modified PDF this missing element has been added to the PDF automatically "repairing" it. Alternatively some object may have been compressed prior to page deletion and during/after page deletion the object is no longer compressed (though file size increase in this scenario would most likely be more than 4k).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample documents that you've provided and @MihaiIancu's comment you are saving an incremental PDF update which basically just appends new information to the end of your existing file.

According to the Foxit SDK site the function [`FSPDF_Doc_StartSaveToFile`](http://tickets.foxitsoftware.com/support/usermanuals/pdfsdk/group___f_p_d_f_d_o_c_u_m_e_n_t.html#ga907000c72bcab16d40f2b6547a1830c1) takes a flag for the third parameter which is [`FSPDF_SAVEFLAG_INCREMENTAL`](http://tickets.foxitsoftware.com/support/usermanuals/pdfsdk/group___f_p_d_f_d_o_c_u_m_e_n_t.html#gac45fb74ee7055e15cef721c0b0384890), [`FSPDF_SAVEFLAG_NOORIGINAL`](http://tickets.foxitsoftware.com/support/usermanuals/pdfsdk/group___f_p_d_f_d_o_c_u_m_e_n_t.html#ga254096f6e29554682097d31b73c4a79f), [`FSPDF_SAVEFLAG_REMOVESECURITY`](http://tickets.foxitsoftware.com/support/usermanuals/pdfsdk/group___f_p_d_f_d_o_c_u_m_e_n_t.html#gae35fdf5c43ea4894bc2fa0085c6469a9) or [`FSPDF_SAVEFLAG_OBJECTSTREAM`](http://tickets.foxitsoftware.com/support/usermanuals/pdfsdk/group___f_p_d_f_d_o_c_u_m_e_n_t.html#gabd00f01328f70f55eef486fe88e9e6c9). In your case I would think that `FSPDF_SAVEFLAG_NOORIGINAL` should do what you're looking for. If you're not using this function directly there should still hopefully be a wrapper that takes one of these parameters.

Comment: I suspect this is correct (I have no way of proving it).  I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Can you look into this some more? I've never used this product before so I'm only making an informed guess. If this isn't correct or you found a better solution the community would be better off if they knew .

Comment: OK.  I just did some fairly extensive testing, and it appears that passing FSPDF_SAVEFLAG_NOORIGINAL does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Foxit PDF SDK 6.4 for Linux the save method supports e_SaveFlagRemoveRedundantObjects.  Usually when you delete a page, it is just referenced in the PDF structure.  If you set this flag, it will just remove any object that is not reference to in the PDF.